# Is it possible to change <div> parent using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to change a div parent programmatically.
For example

```
<body>
  <div id="div_a">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_b">
  </div>
</body>
```

I wonder if it is possible to change the div with id="child" parent to a div with id="div_b" ?

I have search, but nowhere close.
But in case there is a similar question, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: please be more specific, tou want to transform `<div id="child` to a `<div id="div_b` and move it outside `<div id="div_a` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `appendChild` and pass the node as the parameter. A node cannot be in two places at once, so it will move it to the proper location.

```js
let child = document.querySelector("#child");
let parent = document.querySelector("#div_b");

parent.appendChild(child);
```

```html
  <div id="div_a">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_b">
  </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, I'm sorry.
I'm not expert in web programming. But I found this answer is the simplest and met my needs directly. Other answers might work and also true. Unfortunately, I only can choose one. Anyway, I wonder why so many downvote on other answer ?

Comment: @Lyn My guess is that the answer that was downvoted is likely because it didn't really answer the question directly and didn't show actual code.

Answer (score 2):

In pure JS, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append the `#child` div to the `#div_b` div. Since a node cannot exist in more than one place, this automatically also removes it from `#div_a`:

```js
document.querySelector('#div_b').appendChild(document.querySelector('#child'));
// or document.getElementById('div_b').appendChild(document.getElementById('child'));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div_a">
  Div A!
    <div id="child">I am a child of Div A</div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div id="div_b">
  Div B!
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the element to the new parent, then remove it from the old one. If you can use JQuery you can do it easily with

```
jQuery("#child").detach().appendTo('#div_b')
```

with JavaScript

```
var tmp = document.getElementById('child');
document.getElementById('div_b').appendChild(tmp.cloneNode(true));
tmp.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the your application you may want to use querySelector or querySelectorAll to get the div with id="child". Then using [insert element var].classlist() you can .remove('child') and then .add('div_b').